# Cythonize dynamic pyx function

Tags: python, cython

I've created a `pyx` file dynamically, but struggle to cythonize and use the function encoded in it.

I tried

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
import imp
module = imp.load_source('module.name', pyxfilename)
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Does it show any error? Also notice that `pyximport` works only if no extra C libraries and no special building is needed.

Comment: It shows that the `pyx` code is not valid Python code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the function `pyximport.load_module` instead of `imp.load_source` (https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/151d653d3c7ab07e9d961c9601b2ff45202e6ce2/pyximport/pyximport.py#L207).

That appears to build if required then call `imp.load_dynamic`. You call it in the same way as `load_source` e.g.

```
module = pyximport.load_module('module.name', pyxfilename)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't easily test this currently, so it's a bit of a guess, but I'm reasonably confident. Apologies in advance if it doesn't work.

Comment: Excellent! This did the trick. A gotcha is that the `module.name` (the name part in particular) should be different for each pyx file, otherwise the same generated file is used. Also `pyximport.install()` should be called.